# Sequence generator , kata, ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, enumerator

I'm doing this 'Sequence generator' Kata by Ruby, somehow I don't know how to make this happen. But I tried it. Please give me some guildance. Thank you!

> Write a generator sequence_gen ( sequenceGen in JavaScript) that, given the first terms of a sequence will generate a (potentially) infinite amount of terms, where each subsequent term is the sum of the previous x terms where x is the amount of initial arguments (examples of such sequences are the Fibonacci, Tribonacci and Lucas number sequences).

Examples:

```
fib = sequence_gen(0, 1) # returns an Enumerator
fib.next = 0 # first term (provided)
fib.next = 1 # second term (provided)
fib.next = 1 # third term (sum of first and second terms)
fib.next = 2 # fourth term (sum of second and third terms)
fib.next = 3 # fifth term (sum of third and fourth terms)
fib.next = 5 # sixth term (sum of fourth and fifth terms)
fib.next = 8 # seventh term (sum of fifth and sixth terms)


trib = sequence_gen(0,1,1) # returns an Enumerator
trib.next = 0 # first term (provided)
trib.next = 1 # second term (provided)
trib.next = 1 # third term (provided)
trib.next = 2 # fourth term (sum of first, second and third terms)
trib.next = 4 # fifth term (sum of second, third and fourth terms)
trib.next = 7 # sixth term (sum of third, fourth and fifth terms)

lucas = sequence_gen(2,1) # returns an Enumerator
lucas.take(10) = [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76]
```

My Solution:

```
def sequence_gen(e, vs)
  while true
    begin
      vs = e.next_values
      return $!.result
    end
    y = yield(*vs)
    e.feed y
  end
end
```

Best,

Han

Answer (score 2):

**The Code**

You could use an *infinite loop* within an *enumerator*, something like this:

```
def sequence_gen(*args)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    args.each { |e| y << e }
    loop do    
      y << sum = args.inject(:+)
      args = args.drop(1).push(sum) 
    end    
  end
end
```

---

**Explanation**

Now assuming you have some idea of how enumerators work. Let's say we're using the example of `sequence_gen(0,1)` where `args = [0,1]`. Consider this line:

```
args.each { |e| y << e }
```

Our first few terms of the sequence are going to be the arguments passed to `sequence_gen(0,1)`, namely `0` and `1`. This means we first need to yield the arguments 0 and 1 in order. And that's what the code above does.

***Infinite loop***

```
loop do    
  y << sum = args.inject(:+)
  args = args.push(sum).drop(1) 
end
```

The purpose of this loop is to generate the rest of the sequence. The next number in the sequence is the *sum* of the first two arguments, namely `0` and `1` which are stored in the array `args = [0,1]`. We can use `inject(:+)` to do this very easily. This gives us `sum = 1` which using `<<` is yielded via `y`. This also means our next number in our sequence is `1` as well.

At the moment `args = [0,1]` and our sequence is `0,1,1`. To get our next number in the sequence we need to sum the last two numbers in the current sequence, namely `1,1`. We do this by transforming `args` to represent the last two numbers of the sequence. We use `push(sum)` giving `args = [0,1,1]`. Then remove the first element from our `args = [0,1,1]` giving `arg = [1,1]`. We then sum this new array giving `sum = 2` which is the next number in our sequence. Creating this new array is completed by the final line our loop. The summing is done using the first line. Since we're in a loop, these steps get repeated until `3, 5, 8` etc are yielded.

***What do `next` and `take()` do?***

When you define an infinite loop within an enumerator you can control the output-flow depending on your requirements.

`next` takes the next yielded value of `y`. In our example according the order of the code in the enumerator, calling `next` once instructs y to yield `0`. Calling `next` again yields `1`. This is done using the first part of the code (before the loop). Then the loop takes hold and yields the rest of the values, you can in theory keep doing this forever (because you have an infinite loop).

`take(4)` takes the first 4 elements yielded. It's like calling `next` four times in order except the yielded values are saved to an array. Again, because we have an infinite loop we can in theory call `take(n)` for however large `n` we want.

---

**Running the code**

Then running the above code using *Enumerator* methods:

```
puts 'The first seven terms of fib = sequence_gen(0, 1) are:'
fib = sequence_gen(0, 1) # returns an Enumerator
p fib.next #=> 0 # first term (provided)
p fib.next #=> 1 # second term (provided)
p fib.next #=> 1 # third term (sum of first and second terms)
p fib.next #=> 2 # fourth term (sum of second and third terms)
p fib.next #=> 3 # fifth term (sum of third and fourth terms)
p fib.next #=> 5 # sixth term (sum of fourth and fifth terms)
p fib.next #=> 8 # seventh term (sum of fifth and sixth terms)
puts

puts 'The first six terms of trib = sequence_gen(0,1,1) are:'
trib = sequence_gen(0,1,1) # returns an Enumerator
p trib.next #=> 0 # first term (provided)
p trib.next #=> 1 # second term (provided)
p trib.next #=> 1 # third term (provided)
p trib.next #=> 2 # fourth term (sum of first, second and third terms)
p trib.next #=> 4 # fifth term (sum of second, third and fourth terms)
p trib.next #=> 7 # sixth term (sum of third, fourth and fifth terms)
puts

puts 'The first ten terms of lucas = sequence_gen(2,1) are:'
lucas = sequence_gen(2,1) # returns an Enumerator
p lucas.take(10) #=> [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76]
```

outputs:

```
The first seven terms of fib = sequence_gen(0, 1) are:
0
1
1
2
3
5
8

The first six terms of trib = sequence_gen(0,1,1) are:
0
1
1
2
4
7

The first ten terms of lucas = sequence_gen(2,1) are:
[2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76]
```

Comment: What's the relation between ' y << e ' and ' y << sum = args.inject(:+) ' ?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/10/02/enumerator-rubys-versatile-iterator/) for more information on Enumerators.

Comment: From my understanding, ' y << e ' is the outcome from internal iterator and ' y << sum ' is from the external iterator?

Comment: @HanJiang I've added some explanation to help you understand my code further. Enumerators are a tricky concept in the beginning but well worth understanding. So take your time and do some easier examples first if need be.